# using selected datetime value from DropDownList and using it in an sql query condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a dropdownlist which I populated by fetching datetime values that are stored in my database into an AccessDataSource. So when I run my asp.net program I get the following for exemple: 23-DEC-12 12:00:00 AM.
And here is the query I am using in the AccessDataSource:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_time FROM temperature
```

Now what I want to do is take the selected value (datetime value) in this dropdownlist and use it as a condition in an sql query. here is the code I am trying to fix:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cnstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Thermal Analysis\\thermal.accdb";
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(cnstr);
    cn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID,temp FROM temperature where date_time=#'" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + "'# ", cn);
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem?  Do you get an Exception?  Are the results not what you expected?

Comment: Zahi how about using Parameterized query.. also you are doing nothing with dr after this line OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); what do you want to do with the SelectedValue..?

Comment: I am kraze.. I just took the relavent part of the code to post it here :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```

To get the **value** of the drop down list.  The value is what you want to use in your SQL statement.  Also, do look into using Parameterized queries as DJ Kraze mentions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

replace your OleDbcommand statement with this :

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID,temp FROM temperature where date_time=#'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'# ", cn);
```

Comment: Access needs '#' sign when doing selecting on values such as dates

Answer (score 0):

You have used

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = 
      new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID,temp FROM temperature where date_time=#'" 
      + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + "'# ", cn);
```

which is wrong. Because `SelectedItem` is a collection of `Text` and `value` and either you should use text or value

your code should be as follows

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID,temp FROM temperature where date_time='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", cn);
```